# Duplex Printing with MP495?

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

Dear Ubuntu Community,

I recently switched from XP to Xubuntu, I like it very much but at this moment I have an problem.

I often have to print and always use duplex (two-sided printing). I can't find the setting for duplex in CUPS-application or in the web-based CUPS libre-office doesn't give the suggestion either. The printing works just fine (even wireless) only one-sided.

Drivers I used are the official Linux drivers van Canon. See the link.
canon.nl/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/InkJet/PIXMA_MP_series/PIXMA_MP495.aspx

Some search suggested me this program gnome-manual-duplex from canon.nl/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/InkJet/PIXMA_MP_series/PIXMA_MP495.aspx

But than I need the following extra packages; python-gnome2-desktop, python-gnome2-desktop, gnome-shell. I don't wanna have a complete gnome-shell on my system.

Summary questions.

1. Is there a way a I can use duplex printers with these drivers?
2. Will other firmware solve my problem? Some experience from users
   here?
3. Can I use the suggested program without completely downloading
   gnome-shell? It seems a little to much for such a simple program?
4. Any other suggestions are welcome, I'm new to linux but no a complete noob and not afraid of the commandline.

*English is my third language but I tried to be as clear as possible.